# MFC List control and adding array to second column

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a problem with adding an array in to a second column of list contol. The problem is, that the number of filled rows in the second column is the same as the number of filled rows in the first column. My code is :

```
enter code here

for (int i=0; i<velikost; i++) // velikost = 10 (velikost is size)
{
    niz.Format(_T("%d"),polje[i]);
    m_listCtrl.InsertItem(i,niz);
}

polje_stevcev = new int[max]; // new array with size of max number

for(int i=0; i<max + 1; i++) // lets say the max is 90
{
    polje_stevcev[i] = 0;
    niz2.Format(_T("%d"), polje_stevcev[i]);
    m_listCtrl.SetItemText(i,1,niz2); 
}`enter code here`
```

We see in the second for loop that the loop is performed 90 times, but in list control in in second column show me only first 10 rows, others are empty.

Picture (in second column should be 95 rows with number 0, but shows only 10) : [Here is a screenshot](http://shrani.si/f/2t/Be/2PyBZE5A/slika1.jpg)

Thanks.

Comment: Execute InsertItem 95 times. SetItemText works only for existing item.

Comment: Thank you. I made a new loop and execute InsertItem for a blank fields in first column (which are not blank in second).Thanks.